# PowerShell if-statement with "-ge" condition not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple PowerShell script that pulls the latest entry of a specific value from a log file using Select-String, then it checks if the value is greater than or equal to 1000 (typically this value is between 0-10). If the value is greater than or equal to 1000, an alert should be sent using Send-MailMessage.

It seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out why the following script is sending me alerts when the value is far lower than 1000 (when it is equal to 5 or 8 for example):

```
# Log file parsing:
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyMMdd HH:mm:ss"
$LogName = "LOG.log"
$LogFile = Join-Path -Path "C:\DIR1\DIR2\log" -ChildPath $LogName
$LastVALUE = Select-String -Path $LogFile -Pattern 'VALUE:\((\d+)\)' | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value} | select -last 1

# Notification Settings:
$SmtpServer = "redacted.redacted.edu"
$From = "SERVER <server@redacted.edu>"
$Recipients = "<gordy@redacted.edu>"
$Subject = "VALUE Alert"
$Body = "$Date`: Latest VALUE: $LastVALUE"

if ( $LastVALUE -ge 1000 )
{
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -From $From -To $Recipients -Subject $Subject -Body $Body
}
```

This script is invoked every 15 minutes by Windows Task Scheduler. When the value is 0 (which it typically is) no alert is sent (as expected), but when the value is great than 0 but far lower than 1000, an alert is sent.

When testing, if I change the condition to "-le" I receive alerts that accurately show a value of 0 (or close to 0).

I have read through the documentation multiple times to confirm my syntax is correct, but can't seem to find any obvious explanations for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're comparing a string with an integer (`$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` is a string). Because the string is on the left side of the comparison, PowerShell is first converting the integer in the right side (`1000` in this case) to a string and the using the directives for string comparison, see [**Compare strings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0#compare-strings) and [**about Comparison Operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#-gt--ge--lt-and--le).

To put it visually:

```bash
'5' -ge 1000 # true
5 -ge 1000   # false
```

Solution is quite simple, you can either coerce the string into an integer:

```bash
if ([int] $LastVALUE -ge 1000) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Or change the order, putting the integer in the left side so the coercion happens intrinsically:

```bash
if (1000 -lt $LastVALUE) {
    # do stuff
}
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you!
It seems I could I also do the conversion/coercion in a new variable. Something like:
$LastVALUE = '5'
$IntLastVALUE = [int]$LastVALUE